# Is the following propositional function well defined?

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

My question is fairly simple:

Is $(P \wedge Q)(x)$ equivalent to $P(x)\wedge Q(x)$?

Reason I'm asking, is that when I asked my tutor he said the statements weren't equivalent because if $P(x) = "x\ is\ beautiful"$ then $P = "is\ beautiful"$ which to his mind meant something like $(P \wedge Q)(x)$ wasn't well-defined, which to me didn't make much sense.

So, is it well-defined? And if not, why?

Comment: What is a propositional function?

Comment: @GitGud according to my book on Discrete Mathematics, it's a statement, such as $P(x)=x>4$, and it evaluates to True or False

Comment: I had never encountered the term and a quick google search didn't provide me with a clear definition. But it's sensible to assume that for all $x$ in the set of constants, $(P\land Q)(x)$ is defined as $P(x)\land Q(x)$. I'd say they are defined as equal, then obviously they are equivalent.

Comment: @GitGud hey, I asked the tutor and he said they weren't equivalent, so I figured I'd ask here to make sure.. I guess people didn't like me asking

Comment: If you had added that information to the question, I think you'd have gotten less down votes, if any.

Comment: @GitGud done and done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little bit "weird" ...

If we work in *propositional logic*, propositional variables like $P,Q, \ldots$ stands for *sentences*, i.e. something with a definite truth-value, like : "Plato is a philosopher" (which is *true*) and "Napoleon is a painter" (which is *false*).

Thus, we can build up "complex" sentences with the *conncetives*, like $\land$ ("and") that are again *true* or *false* according to the truth-conditions for the connectives (their truth tables).

In my (silly) example :

> "Plato is a philosopher **and** Napoleon is a painter"

is *false*, because $TRUE \land FALSE$ is $FALSE$.

In this context, a formula like $(P \land Q)(x)$ is **not** well-formed, i.e. it is meaningless, because individual variables, like $x$, are not allowed in the syntax of propositional logic.

---

If instead we are working in *predicate logic*, where we have *prdicate* symbols, like $P,Q, \ldots$ and *variables*, like $x,y, \ldots$, we can use $P(x)$ to symbolize the expression "$x$ is a philosopher" and $Q(x)$ for "$x$ is a painter".

Thus, we can build complex expressions like $P(x) \land Q(x)$ meaning, in my example :

> "$x$ is a philosopher **and** $x$ is a painter".

Usually, the syntax of *predicate logic* does not allow for expressions like $(P \land Q)(x)$, but if we want use it to translate the expression :

> "$x$ is a philosopher **and** a painter"

it seems quite clear that it must be equivalent to (the more correct) : $P(x) \land Q(x)$.

---

Your tutor's concern is not very clear ...

According to an "old" point of view (see [Gottlob Frege](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/)), the variable $x$ in the expression for a *predicate* is only a "place-holder".

We can use, instead of "$x$ is a philosopher", the expression :

> "__ is a philospher".

In this case, it is more clear that the expression is incomplete ("unsaturated") and that it must be completed with a "name" in the place indicated by the place-holder in order to get a meningful expression (a *sentence*), like the (true) sentence "Plato is a philospher" or the (false) sentence "Napoleon is a philospher".

The weak point of this convention is that it needs some care to handle predicates expressing $n$-ary relations ($n \ge 2$); writing ; "__ loves __" is ambiguous between "John loves John" and "John loves Mary".

This is why we prefer to use : $loves(x,y)$.

Comment: This very same logic can be applied to this: Given $f=3$ and $g=4$, $(f\circ g)(x)$ make no sense. But given $f(x)=x+3$ and $g(x)=x+4$, the expression $(f\circ g)(x)$ makes perfect sense, as it's equivalent to $f(g(x))$

Comment: Given the term 'function', what came to my mind that is that given one-place predicates $P$ and $Q$ one defines a function $P\land Q$ on the set of constants $C$ by $(P\land Q)(x):=P(x)\land Q(x)$, for all constants $x$ (the choice of $x$ is unfortunate since it's probably reserved as a variable of the language).

Comment: To add something to the above comment, the common terminology 'complex function of real variable' (meaning that the image is a complex number and the objects in the domain are real numbers) suggests that with 'propositional function', $(P\land Q)(a)$ is a propositional formula, for every constant $a$. This fits my interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the propositions are equivalent, by definition.

Comment: What is the definition of $(P\wedge Q)(x)$?

Comment: @Euler'sstudent don't you mean and?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I mean that you define $(P\wedge Q)(x)$ as you define $R(x)$, no matter the logical connective 'in front of' the variable. Thanks.